# Can the topology of a group be defined in terms of the group operation?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

I am trying to digest the concept of a topological group. So far it makes sense to me that some structures (where the topology is already given), may have a continuous operation that also satisfies the axioms of a group.

This led me to wonder if the converse is true. Suppose we have a group, can we define a topology such that the group operation is also continuous? My intuition says such a construction (if possible) would be similar to the weak topology on a family of maps.

Comment: Every group $G$ can be turned into a topological by considering a normal subgroup $H$, and then the topology generated by all cosets $gH$. This will include both discrete and antidiscrete topologies.

Comment: However, there are infinite groups that do not admit a Hausdorff nondiscrete topology. What topology is given by cosets on a normal subgroup I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in a trivial way: you can always take the discrete topology.

More generally, let $G$ be any topological group, not necessarily Hausdorff, and let $G_e = \overline{ \{ e \} }$ denote the closure of the identity. Then you can show that $G_e$ is a closed normal subgroup, and the quotient $G/G_e$ is Hausdorff. We get a short exact sequence

$$1 \to G_e \to G \to G/G_e \to 1$$

where $G/G_e$ is the universal Hausdorff topological group to which $G$ maps. If $G$ is furthermore finite, then any Hausdorff topology on a finite set is discrete, so $G/G_e$ has the discrete topology, and since $G_e$ by definition has the property that $e$ is dense it's not hard to show that $G_e$ has the indiscrete topology. This means the topology on $G$ is generated by the cosets of $G_e$. So topologies on a finite group correspond precisely to normal subgroups $G_e$, and of these only the discrete topology (corresponding to $G_e = \{ e \}$) is Hausdorff.

In the infinite case these topologies associated to normal subgroups continue to exist but also various more interesting things can happen. Probably the two most common types of topological groups are [Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) and [profinite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group), both of which are either finite or uncountable. Nontrivial topologies on countable groups seem uncommon, to me at least.

Comment: A  gind of converse Q is whether we can always deduce the group structure from the topology of a topological group, and the A is NO. Let $<_L$ be the lexicographic order on $\Bbb R^2$ and let $\Bbb R^2$ have the $<_L$-order-toplogy. For $(x,y),(x',y')\in\Bbb R^2$ let $(x,y)+_1(x',y')=(x+x',y+y')$ and  $(x,y)+_2(x',y')=(x+x', y+y'e^x).$ This gives two ordered topological groups with the same topology, but one of them is Abelian anf one of them is not.

Comment: @Daniel: a much easier counterexample is to consider two non-isomorphic groups with the discrete topology with the same cardinality. This can be done with, say, $C_2 \times C_2$ and $C_4$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you, your post has piqued my interest in these groups!